# How to secure communication between ClamAV daemon and Client?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, heroku, clam

I have a Web Application running on Heroku. I want to scan the Uploaded Files.
My *clamd* is running outside of Heroku on a EC2 Instance.
Is the *ClamAV* communication between those two Systems encrypted?
Do i need to take care of the Encryption myself?
Can i configure *ClamAV* to do so or do i need to do it on a Network Level?